# How to unpack double digit hex file with python msgPack?

Tags: python, json, msgpack

I have a text file containing some data, among these data there's a JSON packed with msgPack.

I am able to unpack on https://toolslick.com/conversion/data/messagepack-to-json but I can't get to make it work in python.

Up to now I am trying to do the following :

```
def parseAndSplit(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        fContent = f.read()
        for subf in fContent.split('Payload: '):
            '''for ssubf in subf.split('DataChunkMsg'):
                print(ssubf)'''
        return subf.split('DataChunkMsg')[0]

fpath = "path/to/file"

t = parseAndSplit(fpath)
l = t.split("-")
s = ""
for i in l:
    s=s+i
print(s)
a = msgpack.unpackb(bytes(s,"UTF-8"), raw=False)
print(a)
```

but the output is

```
import msgpack

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marco/PycharmProjects/codeTest/msgPack.py", line 19, in <module>
    a = msgpack.unpackb(bytes(s,"UTF-8"), raw=False)
  File "msgpack\_unpacker.pyx", line 202, in msgpack._cmsgpack.unpackb
msgpack.exceptions.ExtraData: unpack(b) received extra data.

9392AA6E722D736230322D3032AC4F444D44617...(string goes on)
```

I am quite sure that it's an encoding problem of some sort but I am having no luck, wether in the docs or by trying .

Thank you very much for the attention

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the end:

`msgpack.unpackb(bytes.fromhex(hexstring)`

where hexstring is the string read from the file.